# TFS agnostic MSBuild Script

Tags: build, msbuild, tfsbuild

We currently have a "fairly" CI agnostic MSBuild script that is being built on TeamCity.

The script does the following:

1. Versions the assembly attributes using the TeamCity build number
2. Compiles the solution
3. Runs a set of unit tests using NUnit
4. Runs a set of acceptance tests using NUnit and SpecFlow
5. Generates some documentation using Pickles
6. Stores the artifacts
7. Labels / Tags the revision in GIT with the current build number

I say "fairly" CI agnostic because there are a couple of places we publish content to TeamCity via the MSbuild message task.

We have now been given direction from the business to move the build and source from GIT to TFS. The last Microsoft source control I used was SourceSafe and I have no experience with TFS as a CI server. I want to know if we can keep the MSBuild script as agnostic as it currently is and still achieve the same functionality it has now.

Answer (score 2):

You can call an MSBuild script from TFS Build easily.  I believe where it asks for solutions to build you can just give it any MSBuild file (don't know if I've ever specified a non-sln file) but if that doesn't work for some reason, you can do a small tweak to the TFS Build Template and use the MSBuild activity to call any MSBuild script you wish.

You can pass in dynamic parameters to MSBuild by editing the Build Template (or static parameters by editing the Build Definition).

For versioning I usually customize the Build Template to generate a Version # of the format Major.Minor.YYMM.DDRRRR where Major and Minor are arguments set in the Build Definition.  YYMMDD is the date, and RRR I pull from the TFS BuildNumber Revision component (what # build for this build def today).

I use the TFSVersion custom TFS Build Activity from the [TFS Community Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/) to update all my AssemblyInfo's, but if you already have the versioning process in your MSBuild you can just generate the desired version # in the Build Template then pass it as an argument to your MSBuild Activity.

As for publishing files back to TFS you can use a custom MSBuild Task (I'm sure one exists somewhere, but I don't have a link handy), you can call out to the tfs command-line tool, or you can do that in the Build Template (instead of MSBuild) using the provided Workflow Activities.

Comment: So with regard to the versioning we can have tfs push in an msbuild parameter containing the build number and if possible the TFS revision number (or whatever that is in the TFS world)? How would you publish artifacts back to TFS via MSBuild?

Comment: You can push in static parameters to MSBuild by editing the build definition.  If you want to pass in dynamic parameters (such as TFS Build #) you will probably have to edit the Build Template.  TFS has a BuildID (an int), and a BuildNumber which is a string in a format you can customize in the Build Def (by default it is $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

Comment: I have the start of the build, I have had to do a little customization due to the companies complete lock down of the build environment resulting in no access to NuGet. Apart from that it ran the build. What I need to be able to do is push the NUnit results back to TFS so that it can display the results and fail the build if need be.